# Obtain Constant from Properties file?

Tags: java, properties, constants

Is it possible to obtain a constant form a java properties file? I am trying to develop my application so that I can set a flag in a master properties file that dictates whether the application uses the development config file or the production one.

Most of application works fine but Ive hit a bit of a brick wall with the database table mapping in the entity classes. I am using Dynamo DB so the actual class itself requires an annotation as follows:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "table_name")
public class EmailTemplates {
...
```

The tableName value must be a constant and I'm trying to use the following to retrieve the value from the properties file and pass it to the tableName;

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = DynamoTable.TABLE_NAME)
public class EmailTemplates {
...
```

The DynamoTable class:

```
public final class DynamoTable {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.getBundle("ProjectStage").getString("ProjectStage")).getString("EmailTemplates");

}
```

Unfortunately its not working as its saying the value is not a constant. If I simply put a literal string (ie. "aStringValue") then its fine, but not from the properties file.

NB. Just to be clear there isn't a problem with the above code retrieving the values from the properties file. The problem is that its not being treated as a constant.

Comment: @Jeffrey Sorry, Ive added the problem to the end of the post.

Comment: You say you need to define different properties files for production and development. I dont know why you need to make the table name variable, isnt there a separate production database, and development database, cant you play around with the connection string instead of changing the table name?

Comment: Technically yes. But DynamoDB is amazons NoSQL Database and its slightly different to using relational DB's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do what you want to do.

You're asking the javac compiler to *execute* arbitrary code to read a properties file from disk, extract a value, and insert that as a constant into your code (at *compile time*).

As you can see, that's a bit much for the compiler to do.

You can only execute that code at *runtime*, which doesn't suite your situation because you're trying to assign a value to an annotation (and thus the value for the annotation must be available at *compile time*).

Comment: I was worried that was the case, back to the drawing board then... Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the DynamoDBMapper class for your database interaction, there is the option to provide an extra  DynamoDBMapperConfig argument for loads, saves, deletes, queries and scans.

You can build this config at runtime and then pass it into the dynamoDB operations.

```
private DynamoDBMapperConfig getEnvironmentConfig(DymanoTable tableEntity, String environment)
{
    DynamoDBTable annotation = (DynamoDBTable) tableEntity.getClass().getAnnotation(DynamoDBTable.class);
    DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride tableNameOverride = new DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride(environment + annotation.tableName());
    return new DynamoDBMapperConfig(tableNameOverride);
}
```

You will need to create a DymnamoDBMapper...

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(
                ObjectPersistenceQueryScanExample.class.getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties"));

        client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
```

And the use this for your dynamoDB interaction

```
public void save(DynamoTable entity)
{
    mapper.save(entity, getEnvironmentConfig(entity,"dev"));
}
```

Comment: It is pretty weird the way you used to dynamically set the table name. I found your suggestion useful, but I have solved in this way, just passing the `Sting` containing the tablename to the TableNameOverride 
DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride tableNameOverride = new DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride(
    conf.getTableName());